# How to return a Stripe checkout session in Actix Web?

Tags: rust, stripe-payments, actix-web

I am rewriting a Stripe implementation I had in Rust and all is well except I cant figure out how to return the response properly in Actix Web. I can return details such as the redirect url or sessionId as a string but I believe for the redirect to work it needs the checkout session in JSON.

Here is the function declaration for my post request:

```
pub async fn _create_payment_session(Info: web::Json<UserData>)->impl Responder {
    let secret_key = std::env::var("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY").expect("Missing STRIPE_SECRET_KEY in env");
    match CheckoutSession::create(&_client, _params).await {
        Ok(_ok)=> {     
            HttpResponse::Ok()
                .content_type(ContentType::json())
                .insert_header(("X-Hdr", "sample", ))
                .status(StatusCode::from_u16(200).unwrap())
                .body(_ok) 
        }, Err(err)=> {      
            HttpResponse::Ok()
                .content_type(ContentType::json())
                .insert_header(("X-Hdr", "sample"))
                .status(StatusCode::from_u16(501).unwrap())
                .body(format!("could not post data, reason : {}", err))           
        }    
   } // end of match
```

and here is where I am calling my match statement. The issue here is:

```
the trait bound `stripe::CheckoutSession: MessageBody` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `MessageBody`:
  &'static [u8]
  &'static str
  &mut B
  ()
  BodyStream<S>
  Box<B>
  BoxBody
  BytesMut
```

Trying to return the checkout session particularly the id so that the front end can use it to redirect the user to the stripe checkout page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`stripe::CheckoutSession`](https://docs.rs/async-stripe/latest/stripe/struct.CheckoutSession.html) implements `serde::Serialize`, so you can return it as JSON by using [`.json()`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/struct.HttpResponseBuilder.html#method.json) instead of `.body()`:

```
HttpResponse::Ok()
    .content_type(ContentType::json())
    .insert_header(("X-Hdr", "sample", ))
    .status(StatusCode::from_u16(200).unwrap())
    .json(_ok) // <----------------
```